# 2D grid travel (Dynamic Programming) - recursive solution working but not memoized one

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Problem Statement - there's a 2D grid of dimensions m x n ,you are at the top left corner, find in how many ways you can reach the bottom right when you can only move down or right.

The code uses unordered map where the keys are strings like so "2,3" , "1,2" (the nodes in the tree) and their values are integers (no.of ways to reach that node).

[image: visualization of the function gridTraveller(2,3)]

The following is it's code which gives correct output for the recursive function gridTraveller(2,3); the output is 3. But, when compiled with only memoized function gridTravelerMemo(2,3) gives an address boundary error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
unsigned gridTraveller(unsigned m, unsigned n);
unsigned gridTravelerMemo(unsigned m, unsigned n);
std::string keyConvertedToString(unsigned m, unsigned n);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{               
    //std::cout<<gridTraveller(2,3);
    std::cout<<gridTravelerMemo(2,3);
    return 0;
}

unsigned gridTraveller(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1;
    if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 0;
    return gridTraveller(m-1, n) + gridTraveller(m, n-1);
}

std::string keyConvertedToString(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    return (std::to_string(m) + ',' + std::to_string(n));
}

unsigned gridTravelerMemo(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{   
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> memo;
    const std::string key = keyConvertedToString(m,n);
    if (memo.count(key) > 0) 
        return memo.at(key);
    memo[key] = gridTravelerMemo(m-1, n) + gridTravelerMemo(m, n-1);
    return memo.at(key);
}
```

Tried printing the keys and it works, so there's probably something wrong with the line :

**memo[key] = gridTravelerMemo(m-1, n) + gridTravelerMemo(m, n-1);**

not sure what's it though; please anybody?

Comment: You don't need dynamic programming for this. You need to make `m+n-2` steps of which `m-1` are down; these can be done in any order. So the answer is `C(m+n-2, m-1)` where `C` is [the binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: your `gridTravelerMemo` doesn't share the memory. (most likely not relate to "boundary error" though)

Comment: `memo` is a local variable in `gridTravelerMemo`; every invocation of `gridTravelerMemo` gets its own copy. `memo.count(key)` is always zero since `memo` is always empty.

Comment: You don't have the terminal conditions of `m == 1 && n == 1` and `m == 0 || n == 0`, the way you do in `gridTraveller`. You keep subtracting 1 from `m` and `n` until eventually they wrap around to a huge value; then you keep walking until stack overflow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik memo is now made to be global and the function gridTravelerMemo() is made to be static, the address boundary error still persists. And yes, your other binomial coefficient solution works.

Comment: Again, you need to terminate the recursion for small `m` and `n`, the way you do in `gridTraveller`. As written, you are eventually calling `gridTravellerMemo(UINT_MAX, ...)`, and it's a looong way down from there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the error is resolved after adding exactly those terminal conditions after return memo.at(key); And, the code works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a breaker and initialization condition in function `gridTravelerMemo`

Update:

Another problem is, you are initialization unordered map every time in the
`gridTravelerMemo` function so you need to remove this also from the function and initialize it as a global.

Code:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
unsigned gridTraveller(unsigned m, unsigned n);
unsigned gridTravelerMemo(unsigned m, unsigned n);
std::string keyConvertedToString(unsigned m, unsigned n);

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> memo;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //std::cout<<gridTraveller(2,3);
    std::cout<<gridTravelerMemo(2,3);
    return 0;
}

unsigned gridTraveller(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1;
    if (m == 0 || n == 0) return 0;
    return gridTraveller(m-1, n) + gridTraveller(m, n-1);
}

std::string keyConvertedToString(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    return (std::to_string(m) + ',' + std::to_string(n));
}

unsigned gridTravelerMemo(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{

    const std::string key = keyConvertedToString(m,n);
    if (memo.count(key) > 0)
        return memo.at(key);
    if(m==0 || n==0) return 0;
    if(m==1 && n==1) return 1;
    memo[key] = gridTravelerMemo(m-1, n) + gridTravelerMemo(m, n-1);
    return memo.at(key);
}
```

Comment: `m<0` can't possibly be true, seeing as `m` is `unsigned`

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same as `gridTraveller`, plus the pointless busywork of setting up an empty map and checking that it is, indeed, empty. `memo.count(key)` is always zero.

Comment: does not work; error : 
warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]

Comment: String? Huh? Are you aware of `std::pair`?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)